# MYSQL Como deletar uma linha de uma tabela com dependências?

Tags: mysql

É possível deletar uma linha de uma tabela com dependências?
Eu tentei o comando

```
ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Mas aparece o erro

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

O que está de errado?

Comment: Essa sintaxe é do SQL Server e não do MySQL, o ideal é você identificar os registros que fazem referencia a ele e tirar essa referencia antes de deletar, senão sua base vai ficar cheio de inconsistências

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, mas é possível deletar assim mesmo?

Comment: Sim, porém se você deletar somente desativando a validação da Fk, seu banco vai ficar inconsistente para sempre, até vc arrumar esses dados e isso só vai te gerar problemas no futuro

Comment: Ok, obrigado, é mais para efeito de aprendizado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe correta para desativar e ativar FKs no MySQL é

Para desativar:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Para ativar:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

O ideal é não utilizar isso para deletar os registros, pois seu banco de dados vai ficar inconsistente, e sim procurar os registros que estão relacionados com o registro que você deseja deletar e remover essa ligação, após isso você poderá deletar seu registro sem problemas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta